# Javascript autotab keyup/keydown not working in Cordova Android Browser

Tags: android, jquery, cordova

I created an autotab function that switches from input to input when user enter a number. The autotab works great on ios and when using a computer keyboard. It doesnt work in Android with touch events. What is the workaround?

**code**

```js
$('.digits').find('input').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('maxlength', 1);
    $(this).on('keyup', function(e) {
        var parent = $($(this).parent());

        if(e.keyCode === 8 || e.keyCode === 37) {
            var prev = parent.find('input#' + $(this).data('previous'));

            if(prev.length) {
                $(prev).select();
            }
        } else if((e.keyCode >= 48 && e.keyCode <= 57) || (e.keyCode >= 65 && e.keyCode <= 90) || (e.keyCode >= 96 && e.keyCode <= 105) || e.keyCode === 39) {
            var next = parent.find('input#' + $(this).data('next'));

            if(next.length) {
                $(next).select();
            } else {
                if(parent.data('autosubmit')) {
                    parent.submit();
                }
            }
         }
    });
});
```

```css
.verification-code {
    max-width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    /*margin:50px auto;*/
    text-align:center;
}
.control-label{
    display:block;
    margin:40px auto;
    font-weight:900;
}
.verification-code--inputs input[type=text] {
    border: 2px solid #e1e1e1;
    width: 46px;
    height: 46px;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="verification-code">
    <label class="control-label">Validation Code</label>
    <div class="verification-code--inputs digits text-black">
        <input oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*?)\..*/g, '$1');"  class="text-black" id="digit-1" name="digit-1" data-next="digit-2"  type="text" maxlength="1" />
        <input oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*?)\..*/g, '$1');"  class="text-black" id="digit-2" name="digit-2" data-next="digit-3"  type="text" maxlength="1" />
        <input oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*?)\..*/g, '$1');"  class="text-black" id="digit-3" name="digit-3" data-next="digit-4"  type="text" maxlength="1" />
        <input oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*?)\..*/g, '$1');"  class="text-black" id="digit-4" name="digit-4" type="text" maxlength="1" />
        <!--<input id="digit-5" name="digit-5" type="text" maxlength="1" />-->
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be as simple as replacing your [.select()](https://api.jquery.com/select/) method with the [.focus()](https://api.jquery.com/focus/) method. There are also simpler ways to add your events than using find. You could just add a class and attach the events based on that class. Instead of using attributes to find your next input, you could simply use the [.next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/) [DOM Traversal](https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/) method. Also you could probably make your number only check work more simply using [regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions). There are a lot of ways to reduce your code here:

```
  $(document).on('keyup', 'input.text-black', function(e){
      var _this = $(this),
          next = _this.next();
      _this.val(e.target.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''))
      if (!!next && _this.val().length)
      {
          next.focus();
      }
  });
```

I did test this on android, and it appeared to work for me. I've also added a check to verify that the input has a length before moving to the next input.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/7vnae2rL/)

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me, verified on android and iOs

https://github.com/smitdesai16/jquery-pincode-autotab

https://smitdesai16.github.io/jquery-pincode-autotab/index.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is best to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. A code example can be very useful. Link-only responses may become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33953197)